# how to use R package stringr or stringi to concatenate strings with NAs in data table

Tags: r, string, data.table, stringr, stringi

I have a data table that have many columns of street address field, like `NUM`, `STREET_PRE`, `STREETNAME`, `STREETTYPE`,`APT_NO`, `CITY`, `STATE`, `ZIP`. Many rows don't have values in all columns, like `STREET_PRE` or `APT_NO`.

I need to get a address string from these columns. Using paste0 will put string "NA" into the result. I searched and found some discussions about this problem was just replacing "NA" afterwards, or using if else in concatenate. Replacing NA afterwards could bring problem if there is some valid input of "NA".

`stringr`'s `str_c` looks promising because it will skip NAs. However I always get NA as result for this input:

```
>t1 = c(NA, "Charles County, MD", NA, "Charles County", "MD","00000") 
>str_c(t1, collapse = '')
[1] NA
>stri_c(t1,ignore_null = TRUE, collapse = '')
[1] NA
```

This input have some non-standard values but I still expect to get an address string. I'll let the geocoder to determine whether the address is valid.

It seemed to be a simple task but difficult to get what I want. `paste`, `str_c`, `stri_c` seemed all trying to match two vectors and concatenate them, but I only want to concatenate one serial of strings. They all work for normal cases, however the input with NA caused different problems in different functions.

**EDIT** The answer and comments below worked on single row of input but created unexpected result in data table. They may be working on the whole vector of columns when I only want them to work on current row.

I tried these lines without success:

```
address2011_MD_DC[, input_address := paste(na.omit(c(NUM_MILE,STREET_PRE,STREETNAME,STREETTYPE,STREETSUF,APT_NO)),collapse = " ") ]
address2011_MD_DC[, input_address :=
                str_c(na.omit(c(NUM_MILE,STREET_PRE,STREETNAME,STREETTYPE,STREETSUF,APT_NO)), collapse = ' ' )]
```

It could be the collapse parameter combine the column I want into single value. Maybe I have to come back to my original method of using `paste0`, but replace NAs with '' first.

Comment: Can you show the actual format your data is in? (Including the columns?) If it's a single vector, does `paste(t1[!is.na(t1)],collapse=" ")` not yield the desired result?

Comment: It's a data frame/data table with many rows, each row have multiple columns. Yes this also works, thanks!

Comment: Sorry this does not work directly in data.table. Probably the collapse caused unintended result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `stringi` documentation:

> In case of any NA in an input vector, NA is set to the corresponding
>   element. Note that this behavior is different from paste, which treats
>   missing values as ordinary strings "NA".

Try to remove the `NA`s first:

```
library(stringi)
stri_c(na.omit(t1), collapse = "")
```

Comment: Yes I tried na.omit earlier, the direct result of na.omit give some numbers, I haven't try put na.omit inside the stri_c. This seemed work, but I was thinking stringr and stringi should be able to deal with NAs without help of na.omit since they mentioned different treatment of NAs, and have option of ignore_null.

Comment: @dracodoc `NULL` is not the same as `NA`. `NULL` represents the null object in R: it is a reserved word. `NULL` is often returned by expressions and functions whose values are undefined. `NA` is a logical constant of length 1 which contains a missing value indicator

Comment: Using str_c or stri_c in data table seemed to be more complicated than I thought. DT[, address := str_c(na.omit(c(address columns)), collapse = "")]  created unexpected results, actually my R-Studio lost response when I tried to look at the result.

Comment: Why not simply `df$newcol <- apply(df, 1, function(x) stri_c(x[!is.na(x)], collapse = ""))` ?

Comment: Thanks, this do work. However my data table have lots of columns, to use this method I need to pick the columns I need to process first (the t1 in my question is a over simplified example), so it is not really simple for my case. Now I just replace all NAs with ''", then used paste0. With paste0 I have more control of separator, I need some of them to be " ", some of them to be ", ". Of course at last I need to remove extra white spaces caused by empty columns.

Comment: If you could post a `dput()` of your data it would help to come up with a more suitable solution.